Помогите понять как работают атрибуты
Я не пойму как работают атрибуты. Например я  хочу написать атрибут который делает главный поток Main из MTA в STA(я знаю что такой атрибут есть, это к примеру), как именно он связан с этим методом???
Атрибут который "накладывается" к этому методу то он получает как то данные об этом потоке и как то изменяет или как то по другому(возможно я написал глупость так как я понимаю как это работает)

Вы берете слишком сложные и запутанные вещи, которые только путают. Возьмите что-то проще, не потоки, а скажем, валидация, условно "int не больше 10", вот попробуйте решить эту задачу через атрибут, сразу поймете как работают. А так, вам ведь уже в предыдущем вопросе говорили что это и зачем. Если просто, то "атрибут" - это некая метка класса/метода/свойства, и др., которую можно легко найти и затем сделать что-то с этим. Это как, не знаю, стикеры для заметок, взяли листок, написали на нем "пароль 123", приклеили на монитор, вот у вас "пометка" на объекте, которую можете взять и прочитать.

Если разбирать указанные атрибуты, то вот их исходник, как видите, это простые, даже пустые классы, которые просто созданы с целью "пометить" конкретные объекты. Через поиск GitHub можете найти где они применяются, увидите там стандартный поиск атрибута, а дальше банально "если атрибут есть то .... иначе ....". Магии как таковой тут нет.

В большинстве своём, атрибуты добавляют описание (метаданные) для метода, класса, сборки и т.п., к которому они применены. Можно сказать, что это флаг.
Например, когда JSON сериализатор преобразует класс в JSON строку, он извлекает все свойства класса, но если у свойства в описании стоит атрибут [JsonIgnore], то данное свойство пропускается им.
Есть также атрибуты, которые добавляют участки кода. Например, атрибут [DllImport] добавляет код привязки к внешней библиотеки. А [MarshalAs] добавляет код преобразования типа.
Кстати, на базе подобных атрибутов работают аспектно-ориентированные библиотеки.
Есть даже атрибуты условности [Conditional] которые работаю схожим с #if/#endif образом.
